# Meaning of see in the following sentence

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **see** in the following sentence?

> With the legislation now before a parliamentary inquiry, Friday's launch of News Showcase in Australia will see it pay seven domestic outlets, including the Canberra Times, to use their content.

does it mean **to make sure something happens**?

Answer (score 0):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see) offers this meaning for **see**:

> to be the time or place when something happens

A person or organization would "make sure that something happens", but this particular meaning generally has a time or a place as its subject-  in this case "Friday's launch..."

Answer (score 0):

It means that Australia is a place in which something will happen; namely, paying "seven domestic outlets, including the Canberra Times, to use their content."

Answer (score 0):

I think here ***see*** is used metaphorically with the meaning of ***witness, experience, face***. Check entry 9 in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/see):

> If a period of time or a person ***sees*** a particular change or event, it takes place during that period of time or while that person is alive:
>
> - Yesterday ***saw*** the resignation of the acting Interior Minister.
> - Mr Frank ***has seen*** the economy of his town slashed by the uprising.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see) also explains that ***see*** can mean:

> to be the time or place when something happens:
>
> - This summer ***has seen*** the end of water restrictions in the area thanks to a new reservoir.

You can meet such a use of "see" in meteorological contexts:

> ... the heaviest snow will shift from eastern Scotland to south-east England, which ***will see*** a brisk easterly wind accompanying it. ([BBC Weather](https://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/outlook))

but also  in describing political, social, historical etc. situations or changes of a certain time or place:

> India, Iraq, Libya, Pakistan and Philippines all ***saw*** an escalation of civil wars.([Sciencedaily](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2020/12/201217112951.htm))

In an article, the [Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-7895319/Nearly-40-countries-face-civil-unrest-2020-flashpoints-predicted-75-nations.html) uses the verbs ***face*** and ***see*** as synonyms:

> - Nearly 40% of countries around the world ***will face civil unrest*** in 2020.
> - New report states that 47 countries around the world ***saw civil unrest*** last year.